# add-pnpfield -required not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

```
$fix11 = Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Date of Birth' `
  -InternalName DateofBirth `
  -Type Date `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'
```

The `Required` parameter doesn't seem to work, any one experiencing the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fix18 = Add-PnPFieldToContentType `
  -ContentType 'Player Bio' `
  -Field Club `
  -Required
```

The required field needed to be added to Add-PnPFieldToContentType also. That fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

In my test, it working fine. You can go to **Site Settings->Site Columns** and check this column.

[image]

My test script as below.

```
$URL='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team'
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $URL –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$fix11 = Add-PnPField `
  -DisplayName 'Date of Birth' `
  -InternalName DateofBirth `
  -Type Date `
  -Required `
  -Group 'Football Content Types'
```

I run the script in SharePoint Online Management Shell with the latest PnP PowerShell. I suggest you install the latest PnP PowerShell to check if it works.

Comment: How annoying it works for you but not me ! I need to do it via scripting, might try the xml way to add fields via pnp :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me to with just using the `-Required` parameter. Are you running on the latest version of the PnP-PowerShell module?

Try to use a switch and set it to `$true` and see if it work's any better. `-$Required:$true`.